# How to determine integral is independent of path or not?

Tags: integration, complex-integration

I have an integral $I=\int_{0}^{i} \frac{dz}{1-z^2}$
Since it's not analytic at $z=1$ and analytic at all other points. What can I say about path dependence?

Comment: It is not analytic at all other points. What about $z=-1$ ? Anyway, since the integrand is analytic $\forall z\neq 1,-1$ its integral on a path connecting $0$ and $i$ should always be the same as long as the path avoids the two poles. **EDIT:** Not quite. Assuming the path is *not* closed, anyway, If the path is closed, it will either be zero or nonzero depending on whether or not the path encircles the poles.

Comment: If we plot $x=-1$ and $x=1$ on the xy complex plane and take 2 points $y=0 and i$ many path will be analytic. Since there will be 2 lines and integral is taken between them